# How to display locale sensitive time format without seconds in python

Tags: python, time, format, locale

I can output a locale sensitive time format using `strftime('%X')`, but this always includes seconds. How might I display this time format without seconds?

```
>>> import locale
>>> import datetime
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_IE.utf-8')
'en_IE.utf-8'
>>> print datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%X')
12:22:43
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'zh_TW.utf-8')
'zh_TW.utf-8'
>>> print datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%X')
12時22分58秒
```

The only way I can think of doing this is attempting to parse the output of `locale.nl_langinfo(locale.T_FMT)` and strip out the seconds bit, but that brings it's own trickery.

```
>>> print locale.nl_langinfo(locale.T_FMT)
%H時%M分%S秒
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_IE.utf-8')
'en_IE.utf-8'
>>> print locale.nl_langinfo(locale.T_FMT)
%T
```

---

## Solution:

(Based on pixelbeat's answer.)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import locale
def locale_time(t, show_seconds=False):
    if show_seconds:
        return t.strftime('%X')
    replacement_fmts = [
        (u'.%S', u''),
        (u':%S', u''),
        (u',%S', u''),
        (u':%OS', ''),
        (u'ཀསར་ཆ%S', u''),
        (u' %S초', u''),
        (u'%S秒', u''),
        (u'%r', '%I:%M %p'),
        (u'%t', '%H:%M'),
        (u'%T', '%H:%M')
    ]
    enc=locale.getpreferredencoding(do_setlocale=False)
    t_fmt = locale.nl_langinfo(locale.T_FMT).decode(enc)
    for fmt in replacement_fmts:
        new_t_fmt = t_fmt.replace(*fmt)
        if new_t_fmt != t_fmt:
            return t.strftime(new_t_fmt.encode(enc))
    return t.strftime(t_fmt.encode(enc)
```

Usage:

```
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_IE.utf-8')
'en_IE.utf-8'
>>> print locale_time(t)
15:47
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'zh_TW.utf-8')
'zh_TW.utf-8'
>>> print locale_time(t)
15時47分
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest special casing the returned T_FMT as there aren't that many to consider really:

```
$ for l in $(locale -a | grep utf8); do locale | cut -d= -f1 | LANG=$l xargs locale -kc | grep ^t_fmt=; done | sort -u

t_fmt="%H:%M:%S"
t_fmt="%H.%M.%S"
t_fmt="%H시 %M분 %S초"
t_fmt="ཆུ་ཚོད%Hཀསར་མ%Mཀསར་ཆ%S"
t_fmt="%H时%M分%S秒"
t_fmt="%H时%M分%S秒 %Z"
t_fmt="%H時%M分%S秒"
t_fmt="%I.%M.%S %p"
t_fmt="%I:%M:%S  %Z"
t_fmt="%I:%M:%S %Z"
t_fmt="%I.%M.%S. %Z"
t_fmt="%I時%M分%S秒 %Z"
t_fmt="kl. %H.%M %z"
t_fmt="%k,%M,%S"
t_fmt="%k:%M:%S"
t_fmt="%l:%M:%S"
t_fmt="%OH:%OM:%OS"
t_fmt="%OI:%OM:%OS %p"
t_fmt="%p%I.%M.%S %Z"
t_fmt="%r"
t_fmt="%t"
t_fmt="%T"
t_fmt="%Z %I:%M:%S "
```

Comment: t_fmt="%t" is a tab, so obviously a bug. I assume it should have been "%T"

Answer (score 3):

This is bad solution. What happens with some new different locale?

Use following:

```
t.strftime(gettext('%H:%M'))
```

Now each translator for each languages would provide suitable format for each string, for
`en_US` it would be '`%I:M %p`', for zh_TW: `%H時%M分`

This is how usually problems of missing resource in standard localization tools are solved.

Comment: Yes this is the most general solution, but also adds more work for the translators, especially considering they would need to look up strftime formats.  The "H:M" resource is missing but I think it's fairly sensible to infer it from the "H:M:S" resource considering how infrequently new locales (formats) are added.

Answer (score 2):

Consider ICU, and pyICU.

```
>>> from icu import *
>>> locale = Locale('en_US')
>>> dtpg = DateTimePatternGenerator.createInstance(locale)
>>> pattern = dtpg.getBestPattern('hm a')             
>>> sdf = SimpleDateFormat(pattern, locale)           
>>> sdf.format(1507059935.0)                  
u'12:34 PM'
>>> locale = Locale('de_DE')
>>> dtpg = DateTimePatternGenerator.createInstance(locale)
>>> pattern = dtpg.getBestPattern('hm a')             
>>> sdf = SimpleDateFormat(pattern, locale)            
>>> sdf.format(1507059935.0)                   
u'12:34 nachm.'
```

Comment: Though your code may be self-explanatory, your answer would be improved by adding short and simple explanations about what each step of the code does; this helps readers who may not be familiar with the libraries you are using. Good luck on your future SO answers!

Answer (score 0):

The [Babel](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/api/dates.html) library provides an easy and reliable solution for this problem. Here is a sample code using Python 2.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
from datetime import datetime
from babel.dates import format_time

date_time = datetime.now()
formatted_time = format_time(date_time, format='short', locale='en_US')
print formatted_time
```