# Why does Python store German and Spanish (and other?) time format strings as %T in the locale module?

Tags: python, time, locale, string-formatting

I'm writing a test for a program that will be used in multiple locales. While running the test in German, i got the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 454, in _strptime_time
    return _strptime(data_string, format)[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 317, in _strptime
    (bad_directive, format))
ValueError: 'T' is a bad directive in format '%T'
```

Digging into this, i discovered that using `locale.nl_langinfo(locale.T_FMT)` while in German or Spanish (and potentially other languages) produces the format string `'%T'`. This is not recognized in the [`time` module](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime).

The documentation on `locale` at [python.org](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html) doesn't mention anything about returning `'%T'`. The only reference to `'%T'` i could find anywhere is in a response to [a separate StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2507726/534346). From that post and context, i'm assuming `'%T'` is shorthand for `'%H:%M:%S'`.

My question is, how do i handle the locales for which `locale` will return `'%T'` for its format string without doing something like

```
if fmt_str == '%T':
    fmt_str = '%H:%M:%S'
```

to handle those cases?

Comment: +1 Very weird. A standard module errors out unconditionally, with a sucksy error message, simply because of a locale change?

Comment: The problem appears to be that the two modules just don't communicate with each other and `locale` started using shorthand that `time` doesn't recognize. Which is very weird, because they're both supposed to adhere to the unix `date` standard; `locale` does while `time` apparently does not.

Comment: It isn't that my local environment supports `%T`, it's that `locale` uses `%T` as the shorthand for `%H:%M:%S` but `time` doesn't. The abbreviations in `locale` match the formats of Unix's `date` function (to see them, type `date --h` at a command line), but `time` uses a stripped-down list of abbreviations. For the record, `%X` would work, but that's not what is being returned by `locale`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a wholly unsatisfying answer, but this is the answer anyway:

The reason `locale` and `time.strptime` do not play well together is because the `locale` formats were not written for `time.strptime`. They were written for `time.strftime`, to produce necessary date/time formats, not to parse them.

Because `time.strptime` was written to be platform independent, it does not accept as many directives as `locale` gives out; `time.strftime` needs to be able to convert anything thrown at it, so it accepts any platform-defined directive.

So, no, there is no easier way to make `time` and `locale` cooperate the way I want them to.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I see you are using [strptime](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime), not [strftime](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime). And the documentation for strptime mentions:

> Only the directives specified in the documentation are supported. Because strftime() is implemented per platform it can sometimes offer more directives than those listed. But strptime() is independent of any platform and thus does not necessarily support all directives available that are not documented as supported.

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258199/python-datetime-strptime-wildcard), you can use a more powerful date parser, like [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil)

```
>> import dateutil.parser
>> dateutil.parser.parse("Thu Sep 25 10:36:28 2003")
datetime.datetime(2003, 9, 25, 10, 36, 28)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `dateutil` is not a standard module, or at least it is not installed on my workplace's computers. :(

Comment: then, since strptime only support ansi format specifiers you must convert all non-standard ones (that you can). you can use the lists from the documentation of strftime on your platform, like: http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime  (and use a dict instead of 'if's)

Comment: but the best option might be to store all dates as unixtimestamps and only convert with strftime when you need to display them

Comment: Yeah, i'm currently just replacing the unsupported directives with reasonable, supported ones. Between your contributions and looking more closely at the documentation, i've answered my question. Thank you very much.